# Once Spring controller method is invoked can I confirm that the file is completely uploaded?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload an excel file in the OpenShift server data directory (OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR) and store the data in the MySQL database provided by OpenShift. I am following the below steps:

1. Upload the excel file to the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.
2. Read the excel file from OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and parse it.
3. Update/insert the parse data into the database

I am able to upload excel file into the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR with the below code. I use Spring's multipart resolver

```
private void uploadExcelFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
        String fileNameWithPath = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR")+"Test.xls";
        file.transferTo(new File(fileNameWithPath));

        //Start reading the excel file from OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
        .......
        .......
}
```

I will be able to read the excel file from OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, but my concern is I am not sure whether the file is completely uploaded or not at the time of reading the excel.

Once "**transferTo()**" method is executed can I confirm that the file is completely uploaded?

Or, How will I handle it if the file is not completely uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `transferTo()` mothod call, you can do anything you want, with the transferred file.
If you read the doc of the `transferTo()` method, you will see, it is not asynchron.

[Documentation says](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo-java.io.File-):

> ```
> void transferTo(File dest)
>          throws IOException,
>                 IllegalStateException
> ```
>
> Transfer the received file to the given destination file.
>   This may either move the file in the filesystem, copy the file in the filesystem, or save memory-held contents to the destination file. If the destination file already exists, it will be deleted first.
>
> If the file has been moved in the filesystem, this operation cannot be invoked again. Therefore, call this method just once to be able to work with any storage mechanism.
>
> Note: when using Servlet 3.0 multipart support you need to configure the location relative to which files will be copied as explained in Part.write(java.lang.String).
>
> Parameters:
>   dest - the destination file
>   Throws:
>   IOException - in case of reading or writing errors
>   IllegalStateException - if the file has already been moved in the filesystem and is not available anymore for another transfer

Comment: So if the file size is somewhat big, and the network is slow, file upload may take some more time. So will the execution wait at the line transferTo() method until upload is completed?